# Why does __mul__() expect integer arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.  It appears `__mul__()` is expecting an integer only argument.  Did I not define it correctly?

```
# Running Python 3.6.0
from math import sqrt


class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            self.dimension = len(coordinates)
            if self.dimension < 2 or self.dimension > 3:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)

        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Must have at least 2 coordinates and no more than 3. Length = {}'.format(self.dimension))

        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')

        self.magnitude = sqrt(sum([n ** 2 for n in self.coordinates]))

    # This fails with a type error
    def normalized(self):
        try:
            normalized = self.coordinates.__mul__(1.0 / self.magnitude)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            raise Exception("Cannot normalize zero vector")
        return normalized

    # This fails with a type error
    # def normalized(self):
    #     try:
    #         normalized = self.coordinates * (1.0 / self.magnitude)
    #     except ZeroDivisionError:
    #         raise Exception("Cannot normalize zero vector")
    #     return normalized

    # This works fine
    # def normalized(self):
    #     try:
    #         normalized = [n / self.magnitude for n in self.coordinates]
    #     except ZeroDivisionError:
    #         raise Exception("Cannot normalize zero vector")
    #     return Vector(normalized)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.coordinates

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        # Vector scalar multiplication
        return Vector([e * scalar for e in self.coordinates])

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)


# Run the test...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1 = Vector([1.996, 3.108, -4.554])
    print(v1)
    print(v1.normalized())
```

**EDIT:**

Now that I understand what happened I'd like to clarify the answer for anyone who might run into this in the future.

The problem was here:

```
normalized = self.coordinates.__mul__(1.0 / self.magnitude)
```

Which, for the purpose of this explanation simplifies to:

```
a = b.__mul__(c)
```

or

```
a = b * c
```

Here `b` is a tuple and `c` is a number, a real number.

In Python

```
(1, 2) * 3
```

results in

```
(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

In other words the `*` operator applied to a tuple results in the replication of that tuple N times.

Which also means we can't multiply a tuple by a float, it makes no sense.  Hence the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Makes sense.

My error was in that I multiplied the tuple by `self.magnitude` rather than to multiply my `Vector` object by `self.magnitude`, like this:

```
normalized = self.__mul__(1.0 / self.magnitude)
```

Given my definition of `__mul__()` this makes sense and works fine.  And this works too:

```
normalized = self * (1.0 / self.magnitude)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying `__mul__` to the **tuple** `coordinates`. That returns n copies, which clearly requires an integer.

Since you've written a `__mul__` function, you probably meant to call that

```
normalized = self.__mul__(1.0 / self.magnitude)
```

or directly

```
normalized = Vector([e * 1.0 / self.magnitude for e in self.coordinates])
```

Comment: I think this is probably a better guess at what OP is trying to achieve than my answer.

Comment: Can you explain how `__mul__()` applied to a tuple returns multiple copies of the  tuple?  The list comprehension returns a new Vector object with the results of the scalar multiplication.

Comment: I can't see a clear statement in the documentation, but you can test it: `(1,2)*2` = `(1, 2, 1, 2)` - just as `'ab'*2` = `'abab'`

Comment: Ah, OK, that's what you meant.  

In this case I am defining multiplication whereby if my Vector type contains `(1,2)` the result of of `my_vector * 2)` would be a new Vector with coordinates `(2, 4)`.  In other words, there's no replication of the list or tuple N times.

Comment: I'll accept this answer and add some comments/clarification to my question now that I understand what happened.

Answer (score 2):

[`__mul__` applied to a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) (like your coordinates) duplicates the contents of the tuple to increase its length, and hence only makes sense with an integer.

You're trying to multiply eavh element of an array by a number. If you make `coordinates` a numpy array then the multiplication operator will do this correctly. If you want to keep `coordinates` as a tuple then you will need to iterate through it multiplying each element individually (e.g. like in the `__mul__` function you define for your vector class).

Personally I recommend using numpy arrays if possible - they'll make a lot of the maths you're doing quicker and easier if used well.